# VS2008 generated dll has dependency to two different versions of CRT assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dependencies, crt, .net-assembly, vc90

My VS2008 projects generates a dll and links against two other static library. Here is the generated manifest :

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" version="9.0.30729.4148" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

So my dll depends on 2 different versions of the CRT assemblies. How can I know what causes this double dependency and correct this? I would like my dll to bind to the original version of the assembly as it is the default behaviour for vc9.0.

My code does **not** contain any define stating to bind to a specific assembly version as

```
#define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION 1
#define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_ATL_VERSION 1
#define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_MFC_VERSION 1
#define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_OPENMP_VERSION 1
```

or

```
#define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION 1;
```

as desribied on the msdn website [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc664727.aspx)